# how do i place text in tab activity in java in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, tabs

I'm a newb having a try at android studio. How do I place my content in section 1 and some other stuff in section 2 etc. (i created a tabbed activity)
I mean The pre-made code allows me to only edit the string, and place it in all tabs at once. How do i make the selection of only 1st page and insert stuff ?
Anything helps

Sample:

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Strings.xml:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">App name</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settingsy</string>
<string name="section_format">Section text. Taken from strings.xml</string>
```

[image: project screenshot on a device]

Answer (score 1):

Create two Fragments e.g Fragment1 and Fragment2. Create two xml layouts for fragment1 and fragment2 and inflate in corresponding fragments. Then assign each fragment to corresponding tab.

Follow this [LINK](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/). This will help you a lot.